# Trace representation of density matrix question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, trace

System $A$ and system $B$ form a composite system.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace

I wonder why $\rho_{AB}$ cannot be represented as $(\text{tr}_{B}(\rho))\otimes 
(\text{tr}_{A}(\rho))$. I test it on Bell state and they are different. But can you give me a proof?

We know $\text{tr}_{B}(\rho)$ is the density matrix of system $A$.

Comment: You've already found a counterexample to the claim that they're same, as it seems. That *is* proof that they're different. I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Perhaps OP wants to know if this is a pathological case or if there are more counterexamples.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I wonder why

Comment: @kww Maybe you can explain why you find this surprising - **why** would you expect $\rho_{AB}$ to be $\rho_A\otimes \rho_B$?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent $\rho_{AB}$ by $tr_B(\rho_{AB})\otimes tr_A(\rho_{AB})$ only if the two subsystems are not entangled, i.e. $\rho_{AB}=\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$.

Comment: I think even if two subsystems are not entangled, there are special cases when $\rho_{AB}=\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$. That said, I believe $\rho_{AB}=\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$ is not restricted to be the density matrix of product state(s) $\psi_A \otimes \phi_B$.

Comment: This is not entirely correct (at least if "only if" means "exactly if"). A general *separable* (i.e., unentangled) state is of the form $\rho_{AB}=\sum_i \rho_{A,i}\otimes\rho_{B,i}$.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch It should be changed to "only if the two subsystems are can be expressed as a pure product state"